# Download/Read Google Ad Manager Reports using Google Ad Manager Api in C# console Application

Tags: c#, report, google-ad-manager

I am trying to read/download some of the reports i created in Google Ad Manager account using Google Ad Manager Api https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reporting

But couldn't get the results

Also tried NetworkService and InventoryService services of the api to grab some of the data from my google ad manager account which is working correctly as follows:

```
using Google.Api.Ads.AdManager.Lib;
using Google.Api.Ads.AdManager.Util.v201911;
using Google.Api.Ads.AdManager.v201911;
using Google.Api.Ads.Common.Util.Reports;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Google.Api.Ads.AdManager.Examples.CSharp.v201911
{
    /// This example gets all ad units.
    public class GetAllAdUnits : SampleBase
    {
        public string orderId;


        /// Returns a description about the code example.
        public string Description => "This example gets all ad units.";

        /// Main method, to run this code example as a standalone application.
        public static void Main()
        {
            GetAllAdUnits codeExample = new GetAllAdUnits();
            Console.WriteLine(codeExample.Description);
            try
            {
                codeExample.Run(new AdManagerUser());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to get ad units. Exception says \"{0}\"", e.Message);
            }

        }

        private string filePath = "/Users/fazeem/";
        /// Run the code example.
        public void Run(AdManagerUser user)
        {
            using (NetworkService networkService = user.GetService<NetworkService>())
            {
                var network = networkService.getCurrentNetwork();
                Console.WriteLine(
                $"Current network has the network code {network.networkCode} and " +
                $"display name \"{network.displayName}\" and Currency {network.currencyCode}."
                );
            }

            using (InventoryService inventoryService = user.GetService<InventoryService>())
            {

                // Create a statement to select ad units.
                int pageSize = StatementBuilder.SUGGESTED_PAGE_LIMIT;
                StatementBuilder statementBuilder1 =
                   new StatementBuilder().OrderBy("id ASC").Limit(pageSize);

                // Retrieve a small amount of ad units at a time, paging through until all
                // ad units have been retrieved.
                int totalResultSetSize = 0;
                do
                {
                    AdUnitPage page =
                        inventoryService.getAdUnitsByStatement(statementBuilder1.ToStatement());

                    // Print out some information for each ad unit.
                    if (page.results != null)
                    {
                        totalResultSetSize = page.totalResultSetSize;
                        int i = page.startIndex;
                        foreach (AdUnit adUnit in page.results)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(
                                "{0}) Ad unit with ID \"{1}\" and name \"{2}\" was found.", i++,
                                adUnit.id, adUnit.name);
                        }
                    }

                    statementBuilder1.IncreaseOffsetBy(pageSize);
                } while (statementBuilder1.GetOffset() < totalResultSetSize);

                Console.WriteLine("Number of results found: {0}", totalResultSetSize);
            }


            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Create report job.
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            using (ReportService reportService = user.GetService<ReportService>())
            {
                ReportJob reportJob = new ReportJob();
                reportJob.reportQuery = new ReportQuery();
                reportJob.reportQuery.dimensions = new Dimension[]
                {
                    Dimension.ORDER_ID,
                    Dimension.ORDER_NAME
                };
                reportJob.reportQuery.dimensionAttributes = new DimensionAttribute[]
                {
                    DimensionAttribute.ORDER_TRAFFICKER,
                    DimensionAttribute.ORDER_START_DATE_TIME,
                    DimensionAttribute.ORDER_END_DATE_TIME
                };
                reportJob.reportQuery.columns = new Column[]
                {
                    Column.AD_SERVER_IMPRESSIONS,
                    Column.AD_SERVER_CLICKS,
                    //Column.TOTAL_ACTIVE_VIEW_MEASURABLE_IMPRESSIONS,
                    //Column.AD_SERVER_CPM_AND_CPC_REVENUE,
                    //Column.AD_SERVER_WITHOUT_CPD_AVERAGE_ECPM
                };

                // Set a custom date range for the last 8 days
                reportJob.reportQuery.dateRangeType = DateRangeType.CUSTOM_DATE;
                System.DateTime endDateTime = System.DateTime.Now;
                reportJob.reportQuery.startDate = DateTimeUtilities
                    .FromDateTime(endDateTime.AddDays(-8), "Australia/Sydney").date;
                reportJob.reportQuery.endDate = DateTimeUtilities
                    .FromDateTime(endDateTime, "Australia/Sydney").date;

                // Create statement object to filter for an order.
                StatementBuilder statementBuilder = new StatementBuilder().Where("ORDER_ID = :id")
                    .AddValue("id", orderId);
                reportJob.reportQuery.statement = statementBuilder.ToStatement();



                // Run report job.
                reportJob = reportService.runReportJob(reportJob);


                // Download the report
                ReportUtilities reportUtilities =
                            new ReportUtilities(new ReportService(), reportJob.id);

                // Set download options.
                ReportDownloadOptions options = new ReportDownloadOptions();
                options.exportFormat = ExportFormat.CSV_DUMP;
                options.useGzipCompression = true;
                reportUtilities.reportDownloadOptions = options;

                // Download the report.
                using (ReportResponse reportResponse = reportUtilities.GetResponse())
                {
                    reportResponse.Save(filePath);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Report saved to \"{0}\".", filePath);

            }
}
}
}
```

But the reportService section of the code(which is for downloading/reading reports) is throwing this exception: "Faied to get ad units. Exception says "AdManagerApiException: Exception of type 'Google.api.ads.adManager.lib.adManagerApiException' was thrown"

Any help/Suggestion will be highly appreciated. TIA

P.S I was initially looking for directly reading some of the reports from Ad Manager account but couldn't find any detailed documentation about it so end up downloadig then reading it..So If any one have correct way of directly reading reports from ad manager account, Please share that as well.